# Advantages and disadvantages of building web app purely with microservices and hybrid with web framework

Tags: spring, django, microservices, laravel, spring-mvc

Definition:

- Purely microservice: Not using any web framework such as Spring, Laravel, Zend, Django. Web app is a single page app loading data via Ajax calls to web services
- Hybrid: The web framework is still used, only some not all data will be loaded via Ajax calls to web services

My initial thoughts came up with potential problem with login logout and user authentication for the hybrid approach. Is it a problem and is there any more problem?

Answer (score 3):

Frameworks have come a long way.  They're very powerful and get amazing things done.  They've also become so ingrained into the languages they work with that employers have to mention them when advertising a job.  That means you're not a java developer.  You're a spring-java developer.

Maybe you fight your frameworks to save your POJO's from corruption.  Maybe you treat your frameworks like a library.  If so, congratulations on overcoming the will of your vender.

The biggest advantage of microservices is I can make the damn things myself.  After this little rant of mine I think you can guess why that appeals to me.

To me this isn't even a new idea.  It's the old idea of coding in the small.  Not creating a monolith that tries to do everything.  But they have to come up with new names when selling old stuff.

Comment: "Coding in the small" is undergoing a renaissance right now.  After so many "programming in the large" projects have gone wrong, the latest fashion is to simplify, which I think is incredibly important.